# How do I remove a dedicated (DHS) or global hot spare (GHS)?

Tags: storcli

I want to replace a hot spare with a new disk, for example to replace a smaller disk with a bigger one or when the manufacturer does a callback of a series of disks.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Determine enclosure and slot with this command:

```
storcli /c0/eall/sall show
```

That should print something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                Sp Type 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
252:4    12 GHS    - 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX U  -    
...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To remove the disk, you first have to turn it into a "unconfigured good" disk by deleting the hotspare status:

```
storcli /c0/e252/s4 delete hotsparedrive
```

The drive will now look like this:

```
252:4    12 UGood  ...
            ^^^^^
```

Now you can turn it off using

```
storcli /c0/e252/s4 set offline
```

which changes the state to:

```
252:4    12 UGood  - 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX D  -    
                                                                        ^
```

(the value in the "Sp" = Spun column changed from "U" = Up to "D" = Down).